# How to fix "could not find system library libudev" when installing cargo-flash?

Tags: rust, stm32, rust-cargo

Operating system: Ubuntu

- Command 1: `rustup update` --> successful
- Command 2: `rutstup target install thumbv7m-none-eabi` --> successful
- Command 3: `cargo install cargo-flash`

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `hidapi v1.4.2`
process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installgobLzf/release/build/hidapi-aad2646622c847a4/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
error: could not find system library 'libudev' required by the 'hidapi' crate
error: failed to compile `cargo-flash v0.13.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installgobLzf`
```

Comment: I had this exact same issue on the Github "Workflows"/CI runners and the solution below fixed it.

Answer (score 16):

First, install the dependencies and then install cargo-flash:

```
sudo apt install -y pkg-config libusb-1.0-0-dev libftdi1-dev
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
cargo install cargo-flash
```

For details, visit [the cargo-flash crate](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-flash#prerequisites).

Comment: Ran into the same issue. This answer solved my problem. It should be accepted!

Comment: Same issue but I only did the 2 last commands to fix it (with `dnf` instead of `apt-get` on Fedora).